# I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException with my arraylist, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

This class is in a program for a game I'm writing that is basically Space Invaders. I'm getting `Exceptions` for some reason and I don't see why I should be getting them.

Here's the class in question, but I can post all the code if necessary:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    Launcher launcher1;
    Background bground1;
    Shot shot;
    public ArrayList<Shot> shots;
    public int numShots;
    public static int counter;

    public GamePanel() throws IOException {
        super();
        this.shots = new ArrayList<>();
        this.numShots = 0;
        launcher1 = new Launcher();
        bground1 = new Background();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bground1.background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.drawImage(launcher1.baldEagleImage, launcher1.getLxCoord(), launcher1.lyCoord, null);//paint the launcher
        while (counter == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++) {
                g.drawImage(shots.get(i).mcDShotImage, shots.get(i).staticXLauncherCoord, shots.get(i).getSyCoord(), null);
            }
        }
    }

    public void move(GamePanel gamePanel) {
        launcher1.moveX();
        if (numShots > 0) {
            moveShot();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveShot() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numShots; i++) {//loop to move all the shots
            if (shots.get(i).getSyCoord() > 10) { // THIS IS THE ISSUE, but I don't know why
                counter = 1;
                shots.get(i).moveY();
                repaint();
            } else {
                counter = 0;
                shots.remove(i);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void createShots() {
        try {
            for (int j = 0; j < numShots; j++) {
                shots.add(new Shot());
            }
        } catch (IOException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("caught an exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post the full stack trace. You can print it with `Exception#printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
} else {
    counter = 0;
    shots.remove(i);
    repaint();
}
```

You remove an item from `shots` without adjusting `numShots`, causing an index out of bounds exception in one of subsequent iterations.

To fix this, either add `numShots--` in the `else` branch, or use the built-in `size()` method that returns the count of elements in a list instead: unlike `numShots` which you need to maintain, `shots.size()` never gets "out of sync" with the actual count.

Answer (score 1):

In the above line of code what is apparent is the issue is numShots is > shots.size() (because you also remove shots.
Since I couldn't where you are incrementing the numShots, in this piece of code one simple (albeit not sure from your logic perspective) change your for loop as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shots.size(); i++)
```